# MySQLi json_encode - how to get only string key not the numeric key?

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Is there any way when using json_encode to get only the entries with the keys with strings and not the duplicate value but with a numeric key?

Here's the SQL and the PHP:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT employee_profile.first_name,employee_profile.last_name, DATE(employee_timecard_entry.time_in_timestamp) AS date, employee_timecard_entry.hours_worked 
        FROM employee_timecard_entry, employee_profile WHERE time_in_timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND employee_timecard_entry.employee_id = employee_profile.employee_id");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $left_side, $right_side);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $data = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       $data[] = $row;
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
```

And a sample of the output:

```
[
    {
        "0": "Ashley",
        "1": "Boehme",
        "2": "2014-01-04",
        "3": "6.10",
        "first_name": "Ashley",
        "last_name": "Boehme",
        "date": "2014-01-04",
        "hours_worked": "6.10"
    },...
```

I would prefer to only have the last 4 entries instead of all 8. I've searched and found a way to do this with PDO, but I'm too far into this project to be able to change to that. I would also prefer not to sort through them on the client side, or is that the only other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `mysqli_fetch_assoc` & not `mysqli_fetch_array`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Comment: Wow... that easy huh. Thanks